# why isn't this nginx rewrite working?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to redirect `wp-content/uploads/(.*)$` to `images/$1` but this location doesn't appear to be redirecting - why? Would it be more efficient to use `try_files`?

```
 location ^/wp-content/uploads/.*$ {
                rewrite ^/wp-content/uploads/([a-zA-Z\-.]+)$ /images/$1 302;
#               try_files /images/$1 =404;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `~` operator before location regex, so it's not processed as a regular expression but as a pefixed location. By the way rewrite don't accept `302` flag. Use `redirect` flag.

Comment: yep, I was just about to comment, the 302 is screwy as well! Thanks